# How to fix a circuit breaker timed out exception on spawning a persistent actor in akka scala?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-persistence, circuit-breaker

has anyone faced a circuit breaker timeout on akka for persistent systems.
I believe this happens when akka fails to reload saved snapshots of events. I tried bypassing this reload by tweaking the conf and adding `snapshot-store-plugin-fallback.snapshot-is-optional = true` to it. However that doesn’t do the trick either.

I am using a `jdbc-journal` with  `jdbc-snapshot-store`  as `snapshot-store.plugin`

Any help on this is appreciated!

```
Supervisor StopSupervisor saw failure: Exception during recovery. Last known sequence number [0]. PersistenceId [UCPersistenceId], due to: Exception during recovery. Last known sequence number [0]. PersistenceId [UCPersistenceId], due to: Circuit Breaker Timed out.","context":"default","exception":"akka.persistence.typed.internal.JournalFailureException: Exception during recovery. Last known sequence number [0]. PersistenceId [UCPersistenceId], due to: Exception during recovery. Last known sequence number [0]. PersistenceId [UCPersistenceId], due to: Circuit Breaker Timed out.
```

I also get this warning after the exception block.

```
{"logger":"org.mariadb.jdbc.HostAddress","message":"Aurora recommended connection URL must only use cluster end-point like \"jdbc:mariadb:aurora://xx.cluster-yy.zz.rds.amazonaws.com\". Using end-point permit auto-discovery of new replicas","context":"default"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Circuit Breaker timed out is not the actual exception. It's rather a symptom of another exception, the source exception. I would suggest looking the database server logs for the actual exception that happened.

Comment: Thank you! And yes enabling the logging for the amazon java sdk, hikari and the jdbc driver did the trick. The underlying issue was an EC2 error preventing the connection to be established to the database.

Answer (score 0):

As @Debasish-Ghosh (whose book on *Functional and Reactive Domain Modeling* I highly recommend) notes, the circuit breaker exception is just a symptom of another failure.

From the warning, it seems likely that you've configured your journal and/or snapshots to point to a specific Aurora replica rather than the cluster end-point.  If that specific replica isn't available, connections to it will fail and eventually trip the circuit breaker; the effect of that is to make attempts to read from or write to the journal fail fast (so as not to consume excessive resources and to give the DB a chance to recover if the failures were due to overload).

So for this specific issue, I suggest using the Aurora cluster end-point in your configuration, which should make replicas being unavailable a non-issue.